# How to unlock Crucial M550 SSD drive with its known password?

Tags: windows-10, ssd, disk-encryption

My Lenovo Laptop died, the Crucial M550 SSD drive is ok but is password protected. I'm now connecting to the drive via a SATA to USB adapter. The drive is acknowledged, but no way can I get a password dialogue presented to access the drive.

The 'Crucial Storage Executive' can see the drive, it says its 'Security Locked' but again offers no means to enter password & access data.

M550 encryption is via drive hardware so there must be a means to access the data.

How can I either access the drive contents or unlock the drive with the known password.

using Windows 10.

I've tried to set it as the boot drive off a very modern Dell Latitude, but I was not unsuccessful configuring via its boot menu which is very different from any of the web guidance videos & its not intuitive.

Comment: The drive must be unlocked in the computer where the password was set up, so you will need to rely upon your back of the data on the drive.

Comment: in summary, you are saying the SED drive is tied to the computer on which the encryption password was set. If the pc dies for any reason - then the drive is automatically dead as well?

Comment: Yes.  You need to keep good backups for this reason to protect against a machine that dies.

Comment: thanks for info - it does mean these drives take on the reliability of the least reliable component within the computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most (nearly ALL) cases this doesn't work via an USB adapter.

The drive must be connected to a real SATA controller on a computer that supports OPAL complaint SATA password handling. (Most computers with a SATA port technically support this, but not every BIOS plays nice. Some just don't implement the password handling properly or at all).

So you need another computer to connect the drive to with SATA and then copy the data to another medium.
After that you can reset the password to nothing (which removes the password altogether), using the "change password" feature in the BIOS.
That will wipe the drive as well. That is why you need to copy the content to another medium first.

Comment: I put it into another type of lenovo laptop, the bios then asked for the pw - great. Unfortunately this bios would not allow me to enter a space (that I'd used as part of the pw) or UC chars. I suspect had I a 2nd lenovo of the same type as the original it would have worked.

Comment: @Jean Putting spaces or any other character besides A-Z and 0-9 in a Bios handled password is always iffy. It works on that PC with that particular bios version, but no guarantees for anything else. Even just a bios update may cause issues. I've seen bios passwords become invalid by an update, because of an underscore, asterix or exclamation mark. Bios downgrade required the password too, but the new bios version didn't allow the special character to be entered. Computer is bricked in that case if there isn't a force flash without password available.

Answer (score 0):

The drive has a password lock (you put on it or agreed to in setting it up) and the BIOS will have that record. The drive must be in the machine where the password was created.

It is nothing to do with the reliability of the machine.

I have a Laptop Lock (BIOS) AND a drive lock. The drive must be in this machine for me to unlock it.  Yes, I have very good backups.

So there is nothing more you can do here on your own.

You might take it all to a repair person and see if they can get the computer going.